# adding custom view in fullcalendar using react

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm creating a calendar app with react fullcalendar. I need to add custom view, but can find an example how to do it. I have also seen the docs, but can't find anything usefull.

Comment: You can try React-Calender, http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-calendar/
it's customizable & there are tons of options to choose from to make React-Calendar truly yours.Hope this will help.

Comment: Saurabh, I have allready worked with fullcalenar jquery, and it meet my requirements completely.  I want to add a custom view with custom html, let users to add an event, and use event's hover and click functions. Is it possible with react-calendar?

Comment: What exactly did you not understand in relation to the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-views)? Where are you stuck? And what exactly does your custom view need to do, which is not available through the existing fullCalendar views? P.S. I don't think the fact you're using react for your wider application would make much difference here...the creation of a custom view is related only to fullCalendar itself.

Comment: There is no full example in documentation how  to add a custom view. I do it now with jquery, but want to change to react. I need an agenda view with custom html.

Comment: For a completely custom view, the docs only show you the structure you need, I agree. The best thing you could probably do is look at the fullCalendar source code for the agenda view, copy it, and modify it to your needs to make your custom view. Easier than starting from the beginning, especially if you want something which is fairly similar to the agenda view.

Comment: But...you mention you just want some custom HTML. So perhaps you should first consider whether the changes you need can be achieved by hooking into the viewRender and/or eventRender callbacks. This would be a lot simpler than making a custom view. I don't know precisely what you want to do, so all I can do is give you some possible options to explore.

Comment: P.S. I think wanting to "change to react" makes no sense in this context. fullCalendar does not use react or know anything about it. I do not think you will be able to incorporate react concepts into your custom view, because when it comes to the view interacting with fullCalendar it will likely not understand what is happening. I could be wrong, but i sounds like it would cause you more problems than it solves. You can either write your view using jQuery (if using fullCalendar 3 or earlier), or plain JavaScript (for fullCalendar 4, which no longer uses jQuery).

Comment: That doesn't stop you making the rest of your page based on react, but within the calendar I would think it does not make much sense to use react components.

Comment: Thanks ADyson, the main thing is that I'm new in react, and it's difficult for me to add a default custom view. It'll be perfect if I can find any full code for adding any custom view.

Comment: I have now calendar with jquery with custom view in jquery. I can send you a link. I ould like to learn react and use react for my calendar app.

Comment: I feel like you haven't actually read my last comments properly. Why do you want to do this with react? fullCalendar and react do not go together. I really think it will be difficult for you to integrate react with a fullCalendar custom view. I don't think you will find any examples of it because it's not a sensible thing to try and do.

Answer (score 1):

See 'Custom Views with Components' section here - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react